# What is this Google Spreadsheets IMPORTRANGE() Sheet key?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I'm new to Google sheets, and I've got this spreadsheet with some IMPORTRANGE functions in them, and they look like this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE($O$2; "Jan!B33")
```

That first value, $0$2, is supposedly the spreadsheet key, but I'm used to that spreadsheet key coming from the HTML, for example "1QCfFIx6evcghuH4k74_ksqx6P7sb5xzUpRaoQobV6MA", or something like that.

My question is, what is this dollar sign notation, and how do I use it?  Is it even something from Google Sheets or is it something someone mistakenly copied from Excel or another program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an [absolute cell reference](https://www.google.com/search?q=absolute%20range%20reference). (The sheet's key is expected to be read from cell `O2`.)

This range syntax is supported by Excel and Google Sheets.